# import xlwings, missing files from numexpr package

Tags: python, terminal, pip, xlwings, numexpr

I'm trying to get started with xlwings, but am recieving a few errors when I go to import it.

I pulled up my OSX terminal, ran

> pip install xlwings

no problem there. Fired up python

> $ python

then ran

> import xlwings as xw

And it gave me this:

> /users/Joshua/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/cpuinfo.py:53: UserWarning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'arch'
>     stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
>   /users/Joshua/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/cpuinfo.py:53: UserWarning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'machine'
>     stacklevel=stacklevel + 1)
>   /users/Joshua/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numexpr/cpuinfo.py:76: UserWarning: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sysctl'
>     stacklevel=stacklevel + 1):

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the numexpr package

> pip uninstall numexpr
>   pip install numexpr

and doing the same with xlwings, but still recieving this error. :/

Any ideas on how to get the missing files?

Answer (score 0):

xlwings imports `pandas`, if it is installed. Pandas again is importing `numexpr` if it's available. This seems to be not correctly installed. I would reinstall `numexpr` using conda (as you are using anaconda) and if that doesn't help pandas and xlwings. You could also create a new conda environment and `conda install xlwings` to try it out in a fresh environment.